# Element of object in object

Tags: sql, node.js, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

(vuejs3 + axios / nodejs + prisma + sql)

I want to get content of my comment but I cannot.

Can you help me please?

```
    <div class="main">
    <div  v-for="post in posts" class="card">
        <header class="card-header">
            <div class="card-title">
                {{ post.user.name }} {{ post.user.last_name }}
            </div>
            <div class="card-date">
                créer le :{{ post.createdAt }}
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
            <p class="card-content">
                {{ post.content }}
            </p>
            <p>
                
            </p>
            <img src=''  class="fullwidth">
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="card-comments">
                {{ post.comments.comment.content }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsAoq.png)

Comment: Comments is an Array. You have to iterate over it and display each comment. Please also consider this guide on how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok i will read sorry.
I need to create a function or i can iterate with v-for ?

Comment: you can use v-for="comment in post.comments"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `comment` property inside `comments` as comments is an array, To get the comments content you can iterate that further inside `post`.

```
<div class="card-comments" v-for="comment in post.comments">
    {{ comment.content }}
</div>
```

Comment: thanks and how i can have the name of user write comment ? please ?

Comment: for that you have a `userId` property in each comment. So you can get the name of the user based on the userid from the mapping user object.